# How would I get all data from firestore document?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Before you tell me to read the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection), I have. I've tried the examples on there and I haven't gotten it to work.

I am simply trying to get all of the data from the muted section of my database and be able to check if they're still muted. (Basically I need to get their UserId, guild ID, mute start, and mute end data.)

From the docs I've tried:

```js
const mutedDB = db.collection('muted');
const queryRef = mutedDB.where('stillMuted', '==', true);
console.log(queryRef)
```

^ Returns ^
[image]

and

```
const mutedDB = db.collection('muted');
const snapshot = mutedDB.where('stillMuted', '==', true).get();
if (snapshot.empty) return console.log('None')  
        
snapshot.forEach(doc => {
  console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
});
```

^ Returns an error ^

[image]

I'm unsure if I did those correctly, please let me know if there's a way to fix/solve this!

Comment: Firestore queries from web and mobile clients **always** return **all** fields in all matching documents.  If you're observing something different, please edit the question to show the actual documents (perhaps a screenshot) and the debug output that shows differently.  I also suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DougStevenson I've edited the post, let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get()` returns a promise that yields a DocumentSnapshot.  It does not itself return a DocumentSnapshot.  You need to wait on the promise to fulfill in the usual JavaScript way:

```
const promise = mutedDB.where('stillMuted', '==', true).get();
promise.then(snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log('None');
        return;
    }
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
    });
}
```

This is spelled out in the documentation that you linked, so I would still actually recommend that you go back and study the docs again.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new this part of firebase, so it's kinda tricky haha. Thank you though! Works perfectly.